# instantianting a class with dependency injection in scala

Tags: scala

I have a below class UserModel with a companion object,

```
package models

import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.db.Database
import scala.concurrent.Future

class UserModel @Inject()(db : Database) {
      def save( user: UserData): Unit = {        
        val conn    = db.getConnection()
        val isadmin = if (user.isadmin)  1 else 0

        try {
        val stmt = conn.createStatement
        val rs   = stmt.executeUpdate("""INSERT INTO USER(fullname,email,password,isadmin)
        VALUES ('""" +user.fullname+ """','"""+user.email+ """',
        '"""+user.password+ """','"""+isadmin+ """')""")

        } finally {
        conn.close()
        }
    }
}
object UserModel {
   def save( user: UserData): Unit = {
    // var obj = new UserModel 
    UserModel.save(user)
   }
}
```

How do I instantiate this class ?

`var obj = new UserModel`  gives error,

`not enough arguments for constructor UserModel: (db: play.api.db.Database): models.UserModel. Unspecified value parameter db`

Comment: If you want to create a new instance of a class manually (with `new`) just pass all arguments there. If you want to use some _DI framework_ like Spring or Guice - then read its documentation. From what I see you used annotation that is used by both Guice and Spring, and then you tried to instantiate object without any library at all.

Comment: Isn't `not enough arguments for constructor UserModel: (db: play.api.db.Database): models.UserModel. Unspecified value parameter db` clear enough?